# Problems in binary tree implementation code in programming c

Tags: c, data-structures

I was trying for implementing a binary tree in Programming c. It is taking only value but not displaying any expected result. Needed help to implement the binary tree. here i have added my code which is trying for a long time by me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node*left;
    struct node*right;
};
int i,parent;
struct node*root=NULL;
struct node*newnode,*temp[];
void display(struct node*);

void display(struct node *root)
{
   if(root != NULL){
      printf("%d\t",root->data);
      display(root->left);
      display(root->right);
   }
}
void add(int num)
{
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
       newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       newnode->left=newnode->right=NULL;
       newnode->data=i+1;

        if(i==0)root=newnode;continue;
        parent=(i-1)/2;

        if(i%2==0)temp[parent]->right=newnode;

        else temp[parent]->left=newnode;

    }
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("enter a binary number:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
     display(root);

}
```

Comment: Why should it display anything if you never call `add`?

Comment: What's the requirement, a balanced tree, a sorted one, something else?

Comment: danh a balanced tree

Comment: My output will be like this if i have a number 5 then my code will generate automatically five nodes in the output like 1,2,3,4,5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding data to your binary tree before displaying it?

New answer:
I modified your code to arrange data as follows. I hope that's what you were trying to do

```
       1
   2      3
 4   5  6   7 etc

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node*left;
    struct node*right;
};

int i, parent;
struct node*root = NULL;
struct node*newnode, *temp[20];

void display(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t", root->data);
        display(root->left);
        display(root->right);
    }
}

void add(int num)
{
    for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
    {
        newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->left = newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->data = i + 1;
        temp[i] = newnode;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            root = newnode;
            continue;
        }
        parent = (i - 1) / 2;

        if (i % 2 == 0) temp[parent]->right = newnode;

        else temp[parent]->left = newnode;


    }
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("enter a binary number (Max 20):");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    add(num);
    display(root);

}
```

The mistakes you did were not referencing your temp to anything and defining an array without precising the size.

Comment: I edited my answer @NazifaTabassum. I hope it helps :)